# Java - read file with Scanner to create non-duplicate objects

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a graph implementation where I can create a graph by doing the following:

```
Graph<Integer, String> g = new AdjacencyList<>(false);
Vertex<Integer> start = new Vertex<>(1);
Vertex<Integer> two = new Vertex<>(2);
Vertex<Integer> three = new Vertex<>(3);
Vertex<Integer> four = new Vertex<>(4);
Vertex<Integer> five = new Vertex<>(5);
Vertex<Integer> six = new Vertex<>(6);
g.addEdge(start, two, null, null);
g.addEdge(start, three, null, null);
g.addEdge(two, six, null, null);
g.addEdge(three, four, null, null);
g.addEdge(three, six, null, null);
g.addEdge(five, six, null, null);
```

This would output this adjacency list:

```
1: [{source: 1, dest: 2}, {source: 1, dest: 3}]
2: [{source: 2, dest: 1}, {source: 2, dest: 6}]
3: [{source: 3, dest: 1}, {source: 3, dest: 4}, {source: 3, dest: 6}]
4: [{source: 4, dest: 3}]
5: [{source: 5, dest: 6}]
6: [{source: 6, dest: 2}, {source: 6, dest: 3}, {source: 6, dest: 5}]
```

It would be cumbersome to build out larger graphs so I wanted to use `Scanner` to read graph data from text files. The file for the graph above would look like the following with the vertices in the first line and the edges in the following lines.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
1, 2
1, 3
2, 6
3, 4
3, 6
5, 6
```

My `Scanner` attempt runs into reference semantics issues where it adds duplicate edges to vertices. I tried to replicate the manual process I have above but wasn't sure how to bind new vertex objects to variables. Is there a better way to read from files to create multiple objects of different types?

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("starter.txt"));
String firstLine = scan.nextLine();
String[] vs = firstLine.split(" ");
ArrayList<Vertex<Integer>> data = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < vs.length; i++) {
    data.add(new Vertex<Integer>(Integer.parseInt(vs[i])));
}
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String edges = scan.nextLine();
    String[] es = edges.split(", ");
    Integer u = Integer.parseInt(es[0]);
    Integer v = Integer.parseInt(es[1]);
    g.addEdge(data.get(u - 1), data.get(v - 1), null, null);
}
scan.close();
```

```
1: [{source: 1, dest: 2}, {source: 1, dest: 3}, {source: 1, dest: 2}, {source: 1, dest: 3}]
2: [{source: 2, dest: 1}, {source: 2, dest: 6}, {source: 2, dest: 1}, {source: 2, dest: 6}]
3: [{source: 3, dest: 1}, {source: 3, dest: 4}, {source: 3, dest: 6}, {source: 3, dest: 1}, {source: 3, dest: 4}, {source: 3, dest: 6}]
4: [{source: 4, dest: 3}, {source: 4, dest: 3}]
5: [{source: 5, dest: 6}, {source: 5, dest: 6}]
6: [{source: 6, dest: 2}, {source: 6, dest: 3}, {source: 6, dest: 5}, {source: 6, dest: 2}, {source: 6, dest: 3}, {source: 6, dest: 5}]
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not executing both codes together(the hardcoded graph filling and the file based graph filling)?

Comment: Code is pretty much ok for me. it seems you calling the method twice or as @VFX suggest you are running both algorithems.

Comment: That was exactly it! I was using the same graph object. >.< Thank you both! :D

Comment: Tip: In cases like this, stepping through the code using a debugger (or even putting in logging/System.out.println at places) can help narrow down the problem much faster than SO.